# Loop to calculate values between two data frames, with one condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am new to python and started with a small private project and really hope someone can help me with the following:

I was able to webscrsape different financial statements and parse the information into three different dataframes (balance sheet, income statement and cash flow data). I try to calculate ratios between different values in two dataframes based on the stock market symbols (STMS) for specific years, for example for XYZ the ratio of income to the average asset value between Year 1, and 2 (e.g. Income Y1/((Assets Y1+Assets Y2) /2)). For each stms the ratio should be calculated. The difficulty is that the STMS will change depending on what financial statements i will scrape. I want to automatize the ratio calculation so that I cannot just loop for a fixed STMS name but would need a flexible loop based on the stms column in the two data frames.
Is there a chance to iterate according to the stms in the stms column.

```
Dataframe 1
|      Breakdown1     |     Year 1    | Year 2    |   STMS       |
|---------------------|---------------|-----------|--------------|
|          Assets|    |         122   |      125  |     XYZ      |
|          Assets     |         110   |      115  |     XXY      |
```

```
Dataframe 2
|      Breakdown2     |     Year 1    |    Year 2    |     STMS     |
|---------------------|---------------|--------------|--------------|
|          Income     |         10    |      12      |     XYZ      |
|          Income     |         9     |     10       |     XXY      |
```

I hope I could explain what i try to do and someone could give me a hint how to solve this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you trying to calculate this ratio uniquely for each STMS?  And your challenge is that you do not know what STMS's you will encounter ahead of time?

Comment: Hi JCH, yes that is exactly my challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the dataframes and then calcuate the ration:

```py
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="STMS", how="outer")

merged_df["ratio"] = merged_df["Year 1_y"] / (
    (merged_df["Year 1_x"] + merged_df["Year 2_x"]) / 2
)
print(merged_df)
```

Prints:

```
  Breakdown1  Year 1_x  Year 2_x STMS Breakdown2  Year 1_y  Year 2_y     ratio
0     Assets       122       125  XYZ     Income        10        12  0.080972
1     Assets       110       115  XXY     Income         9        10  0.080000
```